What is the smallest known number of states that a one-way cellular automaton needs to be universal?
We know there is an elementary cellular automaton (ECA) with 2 states (Rule 110) that is universal, i.e. Turing-complete.  One-way cellular automata (OCA's) are a subcategory of ECA's where the next state only depends on the state of the current cell and one neighbor.  I believe that one can make a universal OCA with 4 states pretty easily by simulating two cells of Rule 110 with each cell of the OCA.  Does anyone know if it can be done with only three states?

For what it's worth, I've just convinced myself that it can't be done with 2 states, each of the 16 2-state rules has very simple behavior.

What does universal mean?

There are $3^{3^2} = 19683$ 3-state OCAs, compared to $2^{2^3} = 256$ 2-state ECAs, which suggests that the behavior of the former class of CAs should be richer and likely to support all the same kinds of complex behavior, if not more, than the latter. But of course that's not a proof, just a vague heuristic argument. In particular, even though $3^2 > 2^3$, I don't see any obvious way to emulate arbitrary 2-state ECAs with 3-state OCAs.
